# Input data to complicated join table dbgrid

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, delphi-7, dbgrid, tdbgrid

I have a `dbgrid` that I am going to use as input method for my application. Query to that goes by this:

```
select a.tanggal,
       (case a.kode
         when '01' then
          a.jumlah
         else
          null
       end) as SERATUSRIBU,
       (case a.kode
         when '02' then
          a.jumlah
         else
          null
       end) as LIMAPULUHRIBU,
       (case a.kode
         when '03' then
          a.jumlah
         else
          null
       end) as DUAPULUHRIBU,
       (case a.kode
         when '04' then
          a.jumlah
         else
          null
       end) as SEPULUHRIBU,
       (case a.kode
         when '05' then
          a.jumlah
         else
          null
       end) as LIMARIBU,
       (case a.kode
         when '06' then
          a.jumlah
         else
          null
       end) as DUARIBU,
       (case a.kode
         when '07' then
          a.jumlah
         else
          null
       end) as SATURIBU,
       b.jumlahfisik,
       b.selisih,
       b.bon,
       b.uangrusak,
       b.materai,
       b.lain,
       b.jumlahtotal
  from kasir_opname_detail a
  left outer join kasir_opname_header b
    on a.tanggal = b.tanggal
 where a.ptlokasi = '0';
```

This dbgrid will be a field where I can get values to save the data into database. (Not using apply updates, but using a button with insert code in it). However, the columns where I use the case code cannot be filled with anything.

Is there any idea how to put data to those columns? Or is there any other way to make it possible?

Comment: Your DBGrid is probably connected to a DataSource component. What DataSet component does the DataSource uses to fetch its data ? I think you also need to query the RowID for Delphi to automatic allow input

Comment: @GuidoG putting rowid as you suggested didn't work. I need to fill the column I created from the case code (SERATUSRIBU,LIMAPULUHRIBU,etc) but I cannot fill that with anything. I set readonly to false to each column, but also not working.

Comment: This seems like it should be a Master-Detail pair of queries rather than a single query.

Comment: @APC please elaborate. thanks.

Comment: I know almost nothing about DBGrid but I have worked with similar tools in the past. I'm interpreting your table names and your query to infer a one-to-many relationship between `kasir_opname_HEADER` and `kasir_opname_DETAIL`. In which case maybe [something like this article will help you](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Creating_Master-Detail_Relationships).

Comment: What DataSet component do you connect your DataSource component to ?

Comment: @GuidoG I connected my datasource to zquery (zeos)

Comment: I dont know those so cant help with that. But if all fails you could setup a clientdataset between your zquery and datasource